# How come a blank file shows up in my Google App Engine application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to make a basic python application to teach myself Google App Engine. I have the following 2 files.

helloworld.py:

```
import cgi
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import users

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""
            <html>
            <body>
            <form action="/sign" method="post">
            <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>""")


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>You wrote:<pre>')
        self.response.out.write(cgi.escape(self.request.get('content')))
        self.response.out.write('</pre></body></html>')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                              debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

However, when I run this application and visit localhost:8080 in Google Chrome, a blank page shows up instead of the form I was expecting. Why? 200 responses are showing up in my logs.

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --admin_console_server= --port=8080
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
/Users/davidfaux/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/search/search.py:232: UserWarning: DocumentOperationResult._code is deprecated. Use OperationResult._code instead.
  'Use OperationResult.%s instead.' % (name, name))
/Users/davidfaux/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/search/search.py:232: UserWarning: DocumentOperationResult._CODES is deprecated. Use OperationResult._CODES instead.
  'Use OperationResult.%s instead.' % (name, name))
WARNING  2012-06-21 04:30:38,064 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
Warning: You are using a Python runtime (2.7) that is more recent than the production runtime environment (2.5). Your application may use features that are not available in the production environment and may not work correctly when deployed to production.
WARNING  2012-06-21 04:30:38,204 dev_appserver.py:3423] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
INFO     2012-06-21 04:30:38,220 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:647] Running application dev~helloworld on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2012-06-21 04:30:38,221 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:649] Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
INFO     2012-06-21 04:31:00,561 dev_appserver.py:2904] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-06-21 04:31:00,758 dev_appserver.py:2904] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-06-21 04:31:02,091 dev_appserver.py:2904] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-06-21 04:31:02,180 dev_appserver.py:2904] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-06-21 04:31:04,580 dev_appserver.py:2904] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using python 2.5. You are missing the following:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
...
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

See the [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingwebapp) for details.

Comment: Thanks, but my python interpreter reads 2.7 when I open it in terminal.

Comment: But your app.yaml is setting the interpreter as 2.5, because of the line runtime: python. If you want to use python 2.7, you need to specify runtime:python27, and also change the script line. See this guide https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27

Comment: The script line should be changed to script: helloworld.app. Now you are seeing the empty pages because it is executing the file as a cgi, and since there is nothing to execute (basically no main) you get no output and a 200 OK.

Answer (score -1):

It might be that you're missing HTTP headers.  Add this in your request handlers:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
```